# How to display multiple images just below the "main image" in same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created one "main image" in Html. Now i wanted to display multiple images just below the "main image" when i click on "main image" on the  same page. this is my below code which create one "main image" in Html.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <p>The image is a link.</p>
   <a href="default.asp">
    <img src="smiley.gif" alt="HTML" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;">
   </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to display multiple images just below the "main image" in same page?

Comment: Are the images in the default.asp?

Comment: no...default.asp is just used as to make image clickable

Comment: suppose i want to display two images just below when i clicked on main image.where to keep these two images and how to display just below?

Comment: do you want featured image with gallery on below ? like page product in CMC

Comment: just as simple 2-5 different images should appear when i click on main image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbs').hide();
 $('.main-image').on('click', function(){
  $('.thumbs').show(); 
 });
});
```

```css
.outer {
 width:600px; 
 float:left; 
}
.main-image , 
.main-image img { 
 width:100%; 
 float:left; 
 overflow:hidden; 
}
.thumbs {
 width:100%; 
 float:left; 
 margin-top:15px;
}
.thumbs img {
  display:inline-block; 
  width:100px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">

<div class="main-image">
 <img src="about.jpg" alt="about" />
</div>
<div class="thumbs">
 <img src="about.jpg" alt="about" />
    <img src="about.jpg" alt="about" />
    <img src="about.jpg" alt="about" />
    <img src="about.jpg" alt="about" />
    <img src="about.jpg" alt="about" />
    
</div>

</div>
```

this is work for me

Comment: i also wanted to add one more main image with same functionality of previous one.but the only difference is that when i click on first main image,the associated image with first main image should appear and second main image should be disable.in same way when i click on  second main image,the associated image with second main image should appear and first main image should be disable.is it possible to perform how to do?

Comment: $('.main-image').click(function(){$('.thumbs').toggle();
        $('.main1-image').toggle();
     
 });
 $('.thumbs1').toggle();
 $('.main1-image').click(function(){
  $('.thumbs1').toggle();
        $('.main-image').toggle();  
 });

Comment: i did through this.but i dont want to create two div class for two different main image

Comment: you can add a slider for that.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want ?
https://jsfiddle.net/bfahmi/2m16vjj1/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.featured-image').on('click', '#btn-display', function() {
    if ($('.gallery').is(':visible')) $('.gallery').hide();
    else $('.gallery').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.images {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 auto;
}
.featured-image,
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.gallery {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.featured-image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.gallery img {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div class="featured-image">
    <a id="btn-display" href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/?text=featured-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/?text=image-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/?text=image-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/?text=image-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/?text=image-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal with a following code:

```css
img {
  width:42px;
  height:42px;
  border:0;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<p>The image is a link.</p>
<a href="/">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="HTML">
</a>
<div>
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="HTML">
  </a>
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="HTML">
  </a>
  <a href="/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="HTML">
  </a>
</div>
```